# How to get relationship changes logged?

Tags: 4.7, relationships, 4.6, logging

On the [4.7 Drupal 7 Demo site](https://civicrm.demo.civihosting.com) I changed the middle letter of contact [Kathleen Adams](https://civicrm.demo.civihosting.com/civicrm/contact/view?reset=1&cid=76) and it gets logged and becomes visible in the log tab. Then I make a change in the relationship tab, adding a Case Coordinator relationship to Megan Roberts and removing that relationship again. Both these changes to the contact are not logged.

Is there a setting that it will also log these changes? When there isn't such setting available, could this be considered a bug and reported as such?

The same questions for version 4.6.x because that is the LTS version I am using at the moment.

Comment: I tried to set in Administer > System settings > Misc > Logging to Yes, but that did not do what I had hoped for.

Comment: I wouldn't call the lack of it a bug, but it is a feature enhancement - particularly if accompanied by a PR!

Answer (score 2):

If you have enabled the detailed logging it is currently displayed under the target contact of that relationship.

Arguably it would be better if it is shown on both contacts.

You can view all changes in the `Contact Logging Report (Summary)`.

Comment: I did not think to look at "the other side". I'll try that on Monday. Thank you!